# SQL where condition automation using python

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7

I have a python based client and server application. Client sends some data to the server based 
on which server (running on python) runs some query on SQL SERVER database. 
For example let's consider client sends
**a=5,b=10** 
Based on which Server computes :

```
#Server.py
import pyodbc

def test(a,b):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=.;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from sample where a='"+a+"'" and b='"+b+"'"") 
    for row in cursor:
        #doSomething ()
```

Both the variabes a and b are hardcoded inside the execute function.
Now what if I want to automate the whole process and by automate I mean to say what if
client sends **c,d,e,f** **etc** along with **a,b**.
 Do I have to change the server code every time or is there any
process to automate the whole server code irrespective of what client sends?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It should have many solutions but depending on your architecture and the protocols between clients and the server.

For example,
We can define the message between clients and the server must follow below rules:

1. The message must be one json
2. The message must has one node named 'MessageType' or 'MessageID' or 'MessageName'

For your scenario, the message will be like

```
{'MessageType':'BeginSchedule', 'a':'test1', 'b':'test2', 'option1':1, 'option2':'t1', 'ClientID':'xxx'}
```

When the server receives one message from one client and its message type is 'BeginSchedule', then will invoke 'test(a,b)' to consume this request.

If there is another schedule, we can define one 'MessageType'='BeginSchedule2', then implement one handler in server code to consume any request whose MessageType='BeginSchedule2'.

The clients may send dirty data inside the message, you have to add some validators before calling the handler.

The clients may send extra data inside the message, you can design them as the optional arguments for the handler, please refer to:
[Using Optional and Named Arguments](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html)

If you need your handlers accept infinite arguments, please refer to:
[How to use *args and **kwargs in Python](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)

Comment: I was thinking about *args and **kwargs but they will require data validation. Anyway thanks :)